# Incorrect Syntax Near Keyword 'Exists'

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm having issues with a subquery and I can't find a solution to my syntax errors. The goal is to show all Manufacturers that make black sneakers over the list price of $70.

I receive the error "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Exists'."

```
Select ManufacturerName
From Manufacturer
Where Category Exists (Select Category, ListPrice, Color From Product Where 
Category = 'sneakers' And Color = 'Black' And ListPrice > 70);
```

Thank you

Comment: How are Manufacturer and Product related?

Comment: Can you share the tables' structures?

Comment: Manufacturer and Product are related through ManufacturerID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need this :

```
select m.ManufacturerName
from Manufacturer m
where exists (select 1 
              from Product p
              where m.ManufacturerID = p.ManufacturerID and
                    p.Category = 'sneakers' and
                    p.Color = 'Black' And p.ListPrice > 70 
             );
```

Comment: @TannerWilliams. . . Check updated based on your comment.

Comment: That worked! Can I ask why you used "select 1" in the subquery?

Comment: @TannerWilliams, when using a correlated sub-query with `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`, all that matters is that _some_ record exists (or not). Since you aren't actually pulling any data from the sub-query, `SELECT 1` is a low-overhead way to generate the results (or lack thereof). It's the conventional way to do it.